# Returning float value from Assembler DLL to C++ using SSE

Tags: c++, assembly, sse, masm, masm32

I have got a problem with returning a float value from DLL Assembler to C++ program. I suppose that it should be handled in xmm0 register, am I wrong? Here is main file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

extern "C" float _stdcall MyProc1(float begin, float end, float x2 ,float x1, float x0);    //dll assembler

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float suma=0;
    suma = MyProc1(12.75,9.3,0,0,1);
    cout << std::hex<< suma << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my Assembler DLL:

```
.686p
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
OPTION CASEMAP:NONE
INCLUDE C:\masm32\include\windows.inc
.mmx
.xmm

.DATA
    pi dd 3.14159265358979 ; constant

.CODE

DllEntry PROC hInstDLL:HINSTANCE, reason:DWORD, reserved1:DWORD
    mov eax, TRUE 
    ret 
DllEntry ENDP


MyProc1 proc b:DWORD, e:DWORD, x2: DWORD, x1: DWORD, x0:DWORD 

    movss xmm0,[b]  
    ret

MyProc1 endp    

END DllEntry
```

and the return value is -1.#IND, why?

Comment: float type which you used in your function declaration actually use mm0 register as return value, but xmm registers are completely different, probably you should declare your function with type __m128 instead of float

Comment: @arash There is no calling convention on x86 that uses the MMX registers (`mm*`) to pass or return values. Either the x87 floating point stack is used, or SSE registers are used.

Comment: `stdcall` is very specific. floats are returned on the top of the FPU stack. You may use SSE instructions in your function but in the end the float result has to be loaded at the top of the FPU stack. In this simple case `movss xmm0,[b]` should be replaced with `fld [b]`

Comment: Let us say you have a value in xmm0 (mov [b] to xmm0 as an example) and you want to put a 32-bit float (single scalar) onto the top of the FPU stack you can allocate space on the CPU stack, store the 32-bit value to the stack location and then load that onto the top of the FPU stack. Example: `movss xmm0, [b]` `push eax` `movss dword ptr [esp], xmm0` `fld dword ptr [esp]` `pop eax` `ret` . The push could be any 32 bit volatile register (one that can be modified by a function). The value put on the stack isn't relevant. We just want to allocate 4 bytes (you could have used `sub esp, 4` as well)

Comment: Could have been done like this as well `movss xmm0, [b]` `sub esp, 4` `movss dword ptr [esp], xmm0` `fld dword ptr [esp]` `add esp, 4` `ret` . One simplification can be made removing the add `esp, 4` if it appears just before a `ret`. MASM will generate a proper prologue to restore the stack when it sees `ret`

Comment: @Cody Gray the MMX and FPU both using the same registers, but with different names.

Comment: That's true, as far as it goes: MMX aliases over the lower 64 bits of the 80-bit x87 registers. But you cannot simply say that they are the same registers and leave it at that. You cannot use them simultaneously for both MMX and FPU operations. You must issue an `EMMS` instruction to "clear" the registers after they have been used with MMX before they can be used for the x87 FPU, and there is no calling convention that allows returning values in MMX registers, so if you want to return a floating-point value, you effectively *must* call `EMMS` before the end of the function. @arash

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah you'r right, thanks for your information. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very compiler specific, but I'd guess you're using a 32 bit Microsoft compiler.

In this case, as you've defined your function to return a float, you need the result to be placed at the top of the floating point stack.

Check the assembly output of your C++ code to check for certain - you should see an `fst` or `fstp` instruction after the function call.

Comment: Rather than being compiler-specific, it is ABI-specific. The major 32-bit C++ ABIs, at least on Windows, will return a floating point value either at the top of the floating point stack (`fp(0)`) or in `xmm0`/`ymm0`.